# Why are some folders green colored on an external drive in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, efs

i just did a reinstalation of windows, noobish as i am i didnt notice the green colored folders on my external harddrive as i copyed my most beloved files. so i wonder if there is anyway to get pas this freaking cryptated files so i can use them again.

Comment: Sorry, just to get the facts. You had some encrypted files (or the whole volume) on your external harddrive, and you're trying to access them again. They were encrypted with what ? (What program) ? Do you know the password ?

Comment: If you used EFS and didn't save your certificates or the admin's certificates (who would be the recovery agent), odds are you won't  be able to brute force the certificates.  If you have a backup of your system, you can restore your system and export the certificates.  (While you're at it, backup your current certificates if you plan on using EFS.)  Sorry and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

EASEUS' **[Data Recovery Wizard](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/)** can retrieve **EFS - encrypted** files from NTFS partitions. To retrieve the files, encryption **password must be known** or SAM database must be present. User must have administrator privileges.

*Data Recovery Wizard is shareware ($69.95), try before you buy.*